# Tracking changes between development, testing and production

Tags: visual-studio, testing, tfs, migration, alm

In most big enterprise application (Microsoft AX, NAV, SAP) normally the code migrates between different app scenarios: Development, testing, acceptance, production...

We develop with VisualStuido and TFS, and to achieve this we duplicate the database (production and test) and track our modifications manually, checking the TFS log, and generating manually a difference script between database versions, ...

Is it difficult to manage our main application lifecylce, deal with multiple micro-ALM with the customizations for each project/customer it is a lot of work!!

I found tools like Migrator.NET, but it is very manually. Is there a tool to implement this scenarios and track and migrate the changes automatically?

Comment: Have you looked at Erwin or SQLCompare?  RedGate also produces SQL Source Control.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about 'automatically track changes' but from visual studio there is the menu 'Compare Databases' :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435(v=vs.100).aspx

Maybe it could help.

Comment: it's what I'm using now, and it's what I want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

You can easily compare database schema between servers using [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/). SchemaCrawler is a free command-line tool that generates database schema details as text, in a format designed to be diff-ed, but at the same time be human-readable.

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler.